# Any company out there offering enterprise-grade support/maintenance for geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, enterprise

In strictly regulated enterprises, like banks for instance, often it is required to have support/maintenance for the software in usage. From the Ethereum community I know that Parity Technologies is offering something like this for parity. Is anything similar existing for geth?

Comment: I didn't find anything for geth so far, but PegaSys is offering support for their Java client (pantheon).

Comment: Pantheon renamed to Hyperledger Besu.